# In Sitecore Personalize, how can I use the trigger for my full stack triggered experience/experiment in my decision model?

Tags: decisioning, sitecore-personalize

I am creating a triggered experience that is triggered when a session closes. In my decision model, I want to determine personalization based on what happened in the session that closed and triggered the experience.

How can I get the session that has triggered the experience in my decision model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a full stack triggered `experience/experiment` is triggered, the `ref` for the event or session that has triggered the experience is available in a property called entity. Entity can be used in a decision model to retrieve details about the trigger, e.g. details of products added to a cart for an experience triggered on abandoned cart.

Entity contains a session ref if the experience has been triggered by the end of a session, e.g. session close or abandoned cart. Entity contains an event ref if the experience has been triggered by an event e.g. custom triggers.

For details on entity see: https://sitecore.cdpknowledgehub.com/docs/full-stack-best-practices#entity-in-triggered-experiences and https://sitecore.cdpknowledgehub.com/docs/decision-models-testing-and-troubleshooting#testing-triggered-experiences-with-entity